# How, with Gremlin, to return properties from in-vertices the same as I do from out-vertices? (Not as arrays)

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm trying to start traversing from one set of labelled vertices, then get all their in-vertices connected by a particular kind of edge, then from there, return a property of those in-vertices as objects. I can do this same thing with some out-vertices starting from the same set of labelled vertices with no problem, but get a "The provided traverser does not map to a value:" error when I attempt it with some in-vertices.

I have found a workaround, but it is not ideal, as it returns the desired property values as arrays of length one.

Here is how I do the very similar task successfully with out-vertices: 
 `g.V().hasLabel('TestCenter').project('address').by(out('physical').project('street').by(values('street1')))`

This returns things like

```
==>{address={street=561 PLACE DE CEDARE}}
==>{address={street=370 N BLACK STATION AVE}}
```

This is great!

Then I try the same sort of query with some in-vertices, like this:
`g.V().hasLabel('TestCenter').project('host').by(__.in('hosts').project('aCode').by(values('code')))`
and get the above mentioned error.

The workaround I've been able to find is to add a .fold() to the final "by" like this:
`g.V().hasLabel('TestCenter').project('host').by(__.in('hosts').project('aCode').by(values('code')).fold())`
but then my responses are like this

```
==>{host=[{aCode=7387}]}
==>{host=[{aCode=9160}]}
```

What I would like is a response looking like this:

```
==>{host={aCode=4325}}
==>{host={aCode=1234}}
```

(Note: I am not sure if this is relevant, but I am connecting Gremlin to a Neptune DB Instance)

Comment: Also, oddly, adding .limit(n) at the end, where n<=100 or so works exactly as desired, but far more are needed and with larger numbers or without the .limit(n) it returns the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me from the error above and your workaround that not all of your 'TestCenter' have an in edge from type 'hosts'. When using `project` the by have to map for a valid value.

you can do two things:

1) make sure a value will be returned in the `project`:

```
g.V().hasLabel('TestCenter').project('host')
     .by(coalesce(__.in('hosts').project('aCode').by(values('code')), constant('empty')))
```

2) filter does values:

```
g.V().hasLabel('TestCenter').where(__.in('hosts'))
.project('host').by(__.in('hosts').project('aCode').by(values('code')))
```

Comment: Suggestion 1 was not an issue because the codes were always present (and I had tried that already just in case only to get the same old error), but suggestion 2 seems to work! Thank you!!

Comment: Also, any idea why this would work with the where filter and not the way I was originally trying it?

Comment: As I wrote, I think you have 'TestCenter' without an in edge from type 'hosts'. try to run  g.V().hasLabel('TestCenter').not(__.in('hosts')) to confirm this.

Comment: You are correct! I was unaware of this (and it shouldn't be the case) and when I originally tried your first suggestion I got an error, but I must have made a mistake. Thanks again. I wish I had the reputation to upvote your answer.